# How can I order a linq result using an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq-to-sql

I have an array of Ids, in order, using these ids I then issue a linq query, however I want the results of the linq query to come back in the same order that the Ids in the array are in.

Example:

```
int[] ids = new [] {10, 9, 8, 7};

var query = from row in context.Table where ids.Contains(row.Id) select row;
```

How could I ensure that the obtained items are in the same order as those in the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can order the rows by the *index* of their `Id` in `ids`:

```
var query = from row in context.Table
            where ids.Contains(row.Id)
            orderby Array.IndexOf(ids, row.Id)
            select row;
```

---

I'm not sure if the LINQ-to-SQL provider supports this; you may need to perform the ordering using LINQ-to-Objects:

```
var query = from row in context.Table
            where ids.Contains(row.Id)
            select row;

var orderedQuery = from row in query.AsEnumerable()
                   orderby Array.IndexOf(ids, row.Id)
                   select row;
```

or

```
var orderedQuery = context.Table
                          .Where(row => ids.Contains(row.Id))
                          .AsEnumerable()
                          .OrderBy(row => Array.IndexOf(ids, row.Id));
```

Comment: Why just not select from Ids and then search for an appropriate row in table? May be I missed some point of the question...

Comment: @sll: One query selecting multiple rows is likely more efficient than multiple queries selecting one row each.

Comment: @dtb : even considering OrderBy changes for each select?

Answer (score 0):

Use OrderBy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx

Comment: Did you read the question correctly?  The issue is not how to order query but how to order based on the order of values in an external array.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate by Ids and then search for appropriate table entries:

```
// if table contains multiple rows per id
var resultSet = ids.SelectMany(id => context.Table.Where(tbl => tbl == id));

// if table contains one row per id
var resultSet = ids.Select(id => context.Table.Where(tbl => tbl == id).Single());
```